# How do I connect to docker from eclipse for debugging?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, docker

I have a server running on docker. I need to connect to the docker for debugging using eclipse.

Comment: Your question is very broad so, you can use Docker Tools Plugins in eclipse to connect to docker containers....

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your server.
For example if your server is running tomcat as the Application server, so you should add some settings where you want to run the docker container. if you use docker-compose, simply add port environment variables to your service:

```
services:
   server:
      ports:
            - "9000:8000"
      environment:
            - JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
            - JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

if you use docker run, then add the equivalent params:

```
docker run -p 9000:8000 -e "JPDA_ADDRESS=8000" -e "JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket" <YOUR_IMAGE_NAME>
```

then in eclipse, flow:

Run > Debug Configurations... > Right click on "Remote Java Application" > new > YOUR_PROJECT_NAME as the project, 9000 as the port and Standard (socket attach) as the connection type > Apply > Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution from AliReza19330:

With Java 8 which is used in Tomcat 8.5.34-jre8, the `docker run` line would be

```
docker run -p 9000:8000 -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n" tomcat:8.5.34-jre8
```